# ¿Cómo evitar qué se registren usuarios ya registrados?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","trigoyponque2017");


$usuario_em     = $_POST['usuario_em'];
$contra_em      = $_POST['contra_em'];
$confcontra_em  = $_POST['confcontra_em'];
$fecha = date("Y-m-d"); 

if($contra_em == $confcontra_em){
//consulta para insertar
     $insertar = "INSERT INTO empleados (usuario_em,contra_em,confcontra_em,fecha) VALUES ('$usuario_em', '$contra_em', '$confcontra_em','$fecha')";

//ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
 if(!$resultado){
     echo "<script>
           alert('Error al registrarse. Por favor, intenta nuevamente.');
           window.history.go(-1);
           </script>";
 }
 else{
    echo "<script>
           alert('Usuario registrado, ya puedes iniciar sesión.'); window.location='index.php'; </script>";
}

}
else{
    echo "<script> alert('Por favor, verifique la contraseña.');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
}
//cerrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

He probado el mismo código en otros proyectos y funciona perfecto. Pero a la hora de probarlo en este me deja registrar usuarios que ya existen.

Comment: Asegúrate que al campo `usuario_em` le agregaste el **index unique** en la estructura de la base de datos

Comment: el username esta definido como unico en la base de datos?

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No sé qué me paso, pero se me olvido. lel Gracias.

Comment: has una validación que verfique primero que no esté registrado ese usuario en tu base de datos.

Comment: Lo **normal** es: **a.** A nivel de BD indicar un índice del tipo UNIQUE que incluya todas aquellas columnas de la tabla que no deberían repetirse en otras filas. **b.** Antes de ejectuar el INSERT tener una función de validación a la que le envías un SELECT preguntando por las columnas del índice UNIQUE de la tabla. Lo mejor es tener una clase de conexión que incluya además dicha función llamada por ejemplo `siExiste(...)` Al parecer no cumples ni con (a) ni con (b), pues de ser así no se insertarían datos repetidos. Y... **c.** Usa consultas preparadas, para que no te inyecten código SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que en la tabla empleados existe una columna **primary key**, por que si no es así, los datos se pueden repetir.

La estructura de tu tabla seria:

```
create table empleados(usuario_em varchar(15),
                       contra_em varchar(45),
                       confcontra_em varchar(45),
                       fecha DATE,
                       constraint pk_emp primary key (usuario_em)
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que no haces un `LIMIT 1` en tu query?
Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera y me funciona a la perfeccion

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM userslog WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email));
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();

        if ($resultado != false) {
            $errores .= '<li>El email ya existe</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu Base de Datos, busca la tabla "usuarios" y en las columnas coloca el ID como llave primaria (PRIMARY_KEY), eso significara que solo existira 1 usuario con el mismo ID(nombre de usuario)y al intentar agregarlo dira error, te recomiendo colocar un aviso en caso de que eso ocurra. ;)